# Pseudo Label Generation for Generative Cooperative Learning

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, autoencoders, feature-extraction, anomaly-detection

I am trying to implement [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.03962.pdf) for unsupervised video anomaly detection.

The gist of the paper seems to be:

- Create a dataset for an unsupervised setting, by mixing up the train and anomalous videos (section 4)
- Divide each video into $p(=16)$ segments each, so for video $i$ we have the segments $s_{ij}$, $j= 1,2...p$.
- Using a Feature Extractor (ResNext) ,compute a '$d$' dimensional feature vector $f_{ij}$ for each $s_{ij}$. (Section 3.1)
- Use this to (pre)train the Generator (a simple Autoencoder). Once G is (pre)trained, it is used to generate pseudo labels. The pseudo labels from G are then used to (pre)train the Discriminator (D). (section 3.3)
- Pretrained G and D are then put into a collaborative loop, where pseudo labels from D are used to improve G and likewise.

I am having trouble with generating the pseudo labels using G. The paper clearly mentions in section 3.3: "Once G is pretrained, it is used to generate pseudo labels".

So does the pseudo label generation come into play **once training is done**? Like *after* the model is ready, we pass the dataset again and keep note of the reconstruction losses, and generate labels accordingly?

Or are they generated *during* training?

(Section 3.2.2 mentions the pseudo label generation and section 4 mentions the threshold selection).